# Why does numpy silently convert my int array to strings when calling searchsorted?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, type-conversion, binary-search

I found a nasty bug in my code where I forgot to convert an integer from `str` to `int` before looking it up in a sorted array of integers. Having fixed it, I am still surprised that this didn't cause an explicit exception.

Here's a demo:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(1000, dtype=int)

In [3]: a.searchsorted('15')
Out[3]: 150

In [4]: a.searchsorted('150')
Out[4]: 150

In [5]: a.searchsorted('1500')
Out[5]: 151

In [6]: a.searchsorted('foo')
Out[6]: 1000
```

With a `float` array this doesn't work, raising a `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'`.

My main question is: **why does this not cause an exception for an integer array?**

This is especially surprising since you can do both `np.arange(1000, dtype=int).astype(str)` and `np.arange(1000, dtype=np.float64).astype(str, casting='safe')`.

Side questions:

- why is it converting the whole array and not the argument?
- why is the search string converted to `'<U32'`?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.  I suggest filing a bug report.

Comment: @MrFooz I found [this discussion](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5370), which helped me see _some_ logic in this, but it still doesn't answer all my questions.

Comment: A bug report would certainly be more than welcome.

Comment: @Jaime: [here it is](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6061)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior happens because `searchsorted` requires the needle and haystack to have the same dtype. This is achieved using `np.promote_types`, which has the (perhaps unfortunate) behavior:

```
>>> np.promote_types(int, str)
dtype('S11')
```

This means that to get matching dtypes for an integer haystack and a string needle, the only valid transformation is to convert the haystack to a string type.

Once we have a common dtype, we check if it's possible to use with `np.can_cast`. This explains why floats aren't turned into strings, but ints are:

```
In [1]: np.can_cast(np.float, np.promote_types(np.float, str))
Out[1]: False

In [2]: np.can_cast(np.int, np.promote_types(np.int, str))
Out[2]: True
```

So to summarize, the strange behavior is a combination of promotion rules where numeric + string => string, and casting rules where int => string is allowable.