# Error during feature selection

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am trying to do feature selection for multilabel classification.I extracted the features on which model will be trained into X. Model testing is done on the same X. I am using Pipeline and selecting best 100 features-

```
#arrFinal contains all the features and the labels. Last 16 columns are labels and features are from 1 to 521. 17th column from the last is not taken
X=np.array(arrFinal[:,1:-17])
Xtest=np.array(X)
Y=np.array(arrFinal[:,522:]).astype(int)
clf = Pipeline([('chi2', SelectKBest(chi2, k=100)),('rbf',SVC())])
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(clf)
clf.fit(X, Y)
ans=clf.predict(X_test)
```

But I am getting the following error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\50004182\Documents\\callee.py", line 10, in <module
>
    combine.combine_main(dict_ids,inv_dict_ids,noOfIDs)
  File "C:\Users\50004182\Documents\combine.py", line 201, in combi
ne_main
    clf.fit(X, Y)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\multiclass.py", line 287, in fit
    for i, column in enumerate(columns))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", lin
e 804, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", lin
e 662, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", lin
e 570, in _dispatch
    job = ImmediateComputeBatch(batch)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", lin
e 183, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", lin
e 72, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", lin
e 72, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\multiclass.py", line 74, in _fit_b
inary
    estimator.fit(X, y)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 164, in fit
    Xt, fit_params = self._pre_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 145, in _pre_tr
ansform
    Xt = transform.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params_steps[name])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 458, in fit_transfo
rm
    return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\univariate_selec
tion.py", line 331, in fit
    self.scores_, self.pvalues_ = self.score_func(X, y)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\univariate_selec
tion.py", line 213, in chi2
    if np.any((X.data if issparse(X) else X) < 0):
TypeError: unorderable types: numpy.ndarray() < int()
```

Comment: I can't quite picture the data in `arrFinal`. Could you either post a snippet to generate some dummy data or describe the contents of it more fully?

Comment: Also it looks like you might have an `ndarray` somewhere in your `arrFinal` data where you are expecting to have an int. Have you checked the `dtype` of all your columns?

Comment: @JamieBull http://pastie.org/private/jeusjl8nfna0vlelzbnbhq

Comment: Can you check the value of `X.dtype`? It looks like that is the most likely culprit.

Comment: What happens if you use `f_classif` in place of `chi2`?

Comment: @DavidMaust X.dtype returned `<U32`

Comment: @JamieBull I get several warnings using `f_classif` similar to this-
`C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\univariate_selection.py:
113: UserWarning: Features [297 298 299 393 394 395 438 439 440 441 442 443 444
445 446 447 448 449
 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467
 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 480 481 482 483 484 485
 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497 498 499 500 501 502 503
 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512 513 514 515 516 517] are constant.`

Comment: I haven't seen that type used before. Try building X with `X=np.array(arrFinal[:,1:-17]).astype(np.float64)`

Comment: That type is sometimes used when there are strings being cast to an int dtype as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325001/why-does-numpy-silently-convert-my-int-array-to-strings-when-calling-searchsorte).

Comment: @DavidMaust I am getting the following warnings after trying out what you suggested-
`C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\univariate_selection.py:
165: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  chisq /= f_exp`

Comment: Oh, I see. At first I thought <U32 was some kind of unsigned int type. It isn't, it's a 32-char string buffer.

Comment: It looks like `chi2` doesn't like columns containing only `0`s. Try passing it through `X = VarianceThreshold().fit_transform(X)  `, or just add it to your pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after a debugging session in the comments above with @JamieBull and @Joker. The solution we came up with was:

Ensure type is correct (originally string)

```
X=np.array(arrFinal[:,1:-17]).astype(np.float64)
Xtest=np.array(X)
Y=np.array(arrFinal[:,522:]).astype(int)
```

First use `VarianceThreshold` to remove constant (0) columns prior to `chi2`.

```
clf = Pipeline([
      ('vt', VarianceThreshold()),
      ('chi2', SelectKBest(chi2, k=100)),
      ('rbf',SVC())
])
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(clf)
clf.fit(X, Y)
ans=clf.predict(X_test)
```